# String input won't print with space?

Tags: java, string, input

```
System.out.print("\nEnter name: ");
String name = input.next();
System.out.println("Added: " + name);
```

When I input a name like "Ciara Lim", it only reads "Ciara" and disregard "Lim". I figured I should have used `input.nextLine();` as I have researched earlier. But then when I changed that to `input.nextLine();`, it doesn't read what I have input, like this:

```
Enter name: Added:
```

What's wrong? :(

Comment: Can you add more context? What is input?

Answer (score 1):

The space is interpreted as separator between inputs.

If you want to read surname and last name:

```
System.out.print("\nEnter name: (FirstName LastName)");
String name = input.next()+" "+ input.next();
```

This does not solve the problem if you allow more than one FirstName...

Answer (score 0):

use `input.nextLine()` its works fine

`Scanner#nextLine` - Advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that was skipped.
complete Example -

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("\nEnter name: ");
    String name = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Added: " + name);
```

Output -

```
Enter name: Ciara Lim
Added: Ciara Lim
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use nextLine() methode instead of using next()

```
public java.lang.String nextLine()
```

Advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that was skipped. This method returns the rest of the current line, excluding any line separator at the end. The position is set to the beginning of the next line.

Since this method continues to search through the input looking for a line separator, it may buffer all of the input searching for the line to skip if no line separators are present